# Javascript MYSQL Dropdown

Tags: javascript, mysql, drop-down-menu

Apologies in advance if a) this question has already been answered, I did search but am not able to use the answers I've found and b) I am not the a very skilled programmer and am trying to learn...

To make this as short as possible...

- I have a fully functioning site with a searchable and sortable database (that a co-worker pretty much build for me a long time ago, hence why I am extra confused)
- I would like to add a dropdown filter that populates from the database
- The code references javascript and PHP. From what I understand, the PHP populates the table data for me and the javascript triggers the 'show xx entries' filter and the search box - which are both awesome

My issue is I cannot get any code for the dropdown I would like to add to work. I can get the dropdown to populate but not actually filter the data :(

```
<?php


$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'database';
$dbpass = 'password;
$dbname = 'marchmadness';
$table = 'leaderboard';

//connect to the database
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Leaderboard</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.ico" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/listing.css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
            /* This triggers the cool filtering stuff, without this it's just a normal table of data */
            $('table').dataTable({
                "iDisplayLength": 10
            });
        });

function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}


}
    </script>


</head>

<body id="listing">
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="topbox" align="center">
<img src="_Images/maddnessheader.png" width="539" height="296" align="center" /></div>
&nbsp; <br/>
&nbsp; <br/>
&nbsp; <br/>
&nbsp; <br/>
&nbsp; <br/>
&nbsp; <br/>

<?
  $sql="SELECT Title FROM leaderboard"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql); 

$options=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

    $id=$row["leaderboard"]; 
    $thing=$row["Title"]; 
    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$thing.'</option>';
} 
?>


<SELECT NAME=thing> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Choose 
<?=$options?> 
</SELEC
```

T>

```
  <table align="center">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Call Coding (%)</th>
        <th>FizzBack SAT Score (%)</th>

    </tr>
</thead>


<tbody>


<?php


    //get the information from the database
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table`;") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<tr>';

        // print out the data from the database. Notice how the text inside $row[] matches up with the headers in phpmyadmin

        echo '<td>' . htmlentities($row['Title']) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . htmlentities($row['Name']) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . htmlentities($row['CC']) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . htmlentities($row['FZB']) . '</td>';


        echo "</tr>\n";
    }

?>



</tbody>
</table>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think I would have to manipulate the javascript to add what I need, as that's where the the working dropdown and search box come from...  but I suck a javascript :-\  If anyone could help I would REALLY appreciate it.  I can share the existing Java as well if needed :D

Cheers!

Comment: Where is the dropdown?  How is it supposed to filter?

Comment: For starters I'd recommend removing the semi-quote in this line:

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table`;") or die(mysql_error());

and make it look like...

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table`") or die(mysql_error());

That could be throwing your query off.

Comment: The only dropdown you have (or should have) is to select the number of results to display per page. If the sorting buttons are not working correctly you will need to assign sorting rules or something. Look at the documentation for the jQuery datatable http://www.datatables.net

Comment: Could you provide an example output? so we can see what you are trying to sort? (a link to a picture or live page would do)

Comment: Everything works great so far. The table loads and is searchable and sortable. But every time I try to add code to add a filter, the filer pulls it's options from the database, no problem, but does not change the table displayed (and seems to work for everyone else).  I tried to post a pic, but it won't let me.

Comment: Ah, I didn't mean to submit that previous comment so soon... 
THIS is an updated version of the code with a dropbox that populates (has dupes, another issue lol), but does nothing when selected.  I think Im adding it in the wrong spot, but it doesn't work when anywhere else... :-\

Comment: <div id="topbox" align="center">
<img src="_Images/maddnessheader.png" width="539" height="296" align="center" /></div>
&nbsp; <br/>
&nbsp; <br/>
&nbsp; <br/>
&nbsp; <br/>
&nbsp; <br/>
&nbsp; <br/>
  
<?
  $sql="SELECT Title FROM leaderboard"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql); 

$options=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

    $id=$row["leaderboard"]; 
    $thing=$row["Title"]; 
    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$thing.'</option>';
} 
?>


<SELECT NAME=thing> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Choose 
<?=$options?> 
</SELECT>



</div>

Comment: I can email anyone who'd like to help the FULL code, including javascript - it's actually some really great code, the girl who wrote it is amazing and I wish she still worked in my office to help me lol ;)

Comment: you should edit your post to include this code, its not all that helpful here :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, Ive edited a few things which didn't seem quite right and added some code which should hopefully filter stuff. Bit of a guess as I've never used datatables and I dont know what the datatypes are.

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'database';
    $dbpass = 'password';
    $dbname = 'marchmadness';
    $table = 'leaderboard';

    //connect to the database
    $db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Leaderboard</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/listing.css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var table; // used to store a reference later
            $.fn.dataTablesExt.afnFiltering.push(
                function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
                    if (aData[0].toLowerCase() == $('#title_filter').val().toLowerCase()) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            );
            $(document).ready(function() {
                /* This triggers the cool filtering stuff, without this it's just a normal table of data */
                table = $('table').dataTable({ "iDisplayLength": 10 }); // this starts the datatable stuff and returns a reference to it
            });
            $("#title_filter").onchange(function() { 
                table.fnDraw(); // forgot this line - whoops
            });
            function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
                var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
                var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="listing">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="topbox" align="center">
                <img src="_Images/maddnessheader.png" width="539" height="296" align="center" /></div>
<?php
    $sql="SELECT Title FROM leaderboard"; 
    $result=mysql_query($sql); 
    $options=""; 
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $id=$row["leaderboard"]; 
        $thing=$row["Title"]; 
        $options.="<option value=\"$thing\">".$thing.'</option>';
    } 
?>
                <select id="title_filter"> 
                    <?=$options?> 
                </select>
                <table align="center">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Call Coding (%)</th>
                            <th>FizzBack SAT Score (%)</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody>
<?php
    //get the information from the database
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table`;") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        // print out the data from the database. Notice how the text inside $row[] matches up with the headers in phpmyadmin
        echo '<td>' . htmlentities($row['Title']) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . htmlentities($row['Name']) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . htmlentities($row['CC']) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . htmlentities($row['FZB']) . '</td>';
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying Nick, but this seems to have broke the 'Show XXX Entries', the next page function and the sort functions lol :)

Honestly, I think the key to this is in the JavaScript, I am just not skilled enough to be able to figure it out... If ANYONE is able to help and would like a copy of the JavaScript, please let me know and I will email you all of the files. 

Thanks again! :)

Comment: All i've really added was javascript and fixed a problem with your generation of the select input box. Its hard to work on something that I cant debug myself. Your issue is with the datatable, you need to read the documentation about custom filters.

Comment: I will continue to read up on it, but it seems when I use your code, not only does the new dropdown not work, but it removes features that were previously working.  I honestly think the solution lies within the JavaScript (unfortunately for me) :(

Comment: Datatables is javascript, without access to the output (including sample data) of your page no one will really be able to help. Going to stop as I'm becoming a bit of a broken record.....

Comment: I've offered to share the files with anyone who would like to try to help, as it's too much to post here and the page lives on a secured server that I cannot give access to.
I realize I don't exactly know what I'm talking about and maybe I don't understand what your talking about 100% either... But, I am trying to learn, patience is appreciated.
Thanks again for trying ;)

Comment: It doesn't have to be live. you could save an output and put it on pastebin. Or replace the php in your example with the resulting code.